# Css two headlines in the same line

Tags: html, css, header, inline

Begginers question but how can I put two headers on the same line?

I have already tried to use display:inline-block, span.
Float cant make them inline and near each other.

Can some help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

The flex display type is made to do this. First, you'll need a flex container, which will hold the headings inside. This should have CSS property `display: flex`.

Then, with the headers, you can use the `flex` css property to dictate how much space they should have within that row. If both have `flex: 1`, they will take up equal amounts of space. If one has `flex: 2` and the other has `flex: 1`, the first one will take up 2/3 of the row and the second one will take up 1/3 of the row.

For more reading about flex, you can see this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container > h1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <h1>Heading 2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use float, as in my example.

```css
h1 {
float:left;
/* if you want them to separate add some margins */
margin-right: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading A</h1>
<h1>Heading B</h1>
```